# verbose mode for Vaadin node npm install

Tags: vaadin, npm-install

How can I activate the --verbose mode for the node npm install run started by Vaadin 23.1.15?

I use Java 17, Gradle 7.4.2, Eclipse 22-3 and Windows. I have the problem that node npm install often hangs during vaadinBuildFrontend Gradle task execution. I use Gradle with --no-daemon option.

2022-11-15 09:59:05,566 INFO  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] TaskUpdatePackages - using 'C:\Users \ --- \ .vaadin\node\node.exe C:\Users \ --- \ .vaadin\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js --no-update-notifier --no-audit --scripts-prepend-node-path=true --ignore-scripts install' for frontend package installation